# How to restrict add to cart for GENERAL group

Tags: magento-1.8, cart, customer-group

I have restricted add to cart for not logged customer, but need also funcionality to restrict it for General group. How to do it?
Part off my code

```
<!--moj kod usun add to cart-->
                <?php if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) { ?>
                    <div class="add-to-box">
                          <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php //echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <!--koniec mojego kodu-->
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to create a module with an observer that is listening to the event `catalog_product_is_salable_after`.

Then in your observer you could do the following:

```
$salable = $oObserver->getEvent()->getSalable();
if (user is not logged in OR user is part of group general) {
    $salable->setIsSalable(false);
}
```

This way you would not have to update an template files and it should be fairly upgrade safe.

**Note: That this simply hides the button and if the user guesses the url correctly they can still add the product to the cart for that I would recommend listening to `catalog_product_type_prepare_full_options` as well**

Answer (score 0):

When a user is logged in the group information can be found in the `customer/session`.
To get more detailed information on the group, you can use the following snippet.

```
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
    $groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();

    // it's best to load the group to get the group code for matching instead of the id
    $group = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId);

    // do your thing here
}
```

Comment: I'm new in magento, sorry. How can I use this snippet? Can you explain me a bit more?

Comment: To start with you could add the logic to the template you already changed in your question. There you should do a check on `$group->getCode()` whether the current user is part of the group you wish to enable to add products to the basket. So, like in the snippet, use the `getCustomerGroupId()` call on the session to get the ID of the group, and afterwards use that ID to fetch the group data.

When you get that part working I suggest you move the logic to a helper to keep your templates cleaner.

Comment: Ok, I have it just to change first line for:
<?php if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId()>1) { ?>

Comment: That should do the trick. But code-wise its better to match against the code (see the snippet in my answer) of the group instead of the ID. The ID doesn't tell a lot when other developers look at your code.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm noob and don't understtod a lot of thing in Magento. I think, that all developer can look at there PA/Customers/Group Customers and then they will see all ID's :). One more time Thank you Tim.

Answer (score 0):

You can use event `checkout_cart_product_add_after` , put this code in `yourmodule/etc/config.xml`

```
         <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                <observers>
                    <yourmodule>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>yourmodule/observer</class>
                        <method>restrictAddToCart</method>
                    </yourmodule>
                </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
```

Also in `observer.php` put this code

```
public function restrictAddToCart(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){    
  if(check for group condition){
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addNotice("Set warning message here !");                            
                         $url =Mage::getModel('core/url')->getUrl('checkout/cart');
                        Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
                        Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
                        exit;   
   }
}
```